# How to dynamically set title in mail command

Tags: linux, grep, sendmail

I am newbie in Linux. I'd like to dynamically set the title of mail command. e.g.

```
command 1>&2 | mail -s "error" abc@gmail.com

command 1>&2 | mail -s "success" abc@gmail.com
```

the previous command returns different result to the mail command. Is there any way to set the title by searching the keyword in the output of previous command? If there is 'error', the title will be set to 'error' correspondingly. Thank everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So the previous command is `command`. So you want to search its output and create a subject from it, and then you want the entire contents as the body. Am I correct?

What if you store the output in a variable?

```
output="`command 1>&2`"
```

Then, you could examine it as you wish (not perfect but hopefully a start):

```
success="`echo ${output} | sed -e 's/blah/blah/'`"
```

You'd still have the output contents available to mail:

```
echo ${output} | mail -s "${success}" abc@gmail.com
```

Comment: Actually `output="$(command 1>&2)"` is better (more readable, and the `$(` ... `)` is nestable....)